# Transforming $2D$ coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Lets say from coordinate system 1, we have 3 points which consists of a triangle. The vertices are located at $(50,120) , (70,150) , (100,100)$. Now, coordinate system 2 consists also of a triangle, whose vertices are located at $(20,60) , (90,200) , (190,30)$.

Now, how can we derive a function / mapping, such that, if I input the coordinates (from system 1) $(50,120)$, the resulting output is $(20,60)$.

How can we do it?

Thanks

Edit:

and if it is possible, what if we say, we have point $(75,110)$ on system1, is it possible to find its transformed point on system2?

Comment: Look up the [Triad Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triad_method) for for 2D

Comment: Do you want the mapping to include offset, scaling and rotation?

Comment: @IvanMatala Please look at Update 5. Your system 2 points (see matrix $B$) give three straight lines. But you original data from system 1 (see matrix $A$) is not that straight. In fact the affine transform ($T A$) does magnifiy and scale them quite nice (see the pattern in cyan colour). It just does not straigthen them and I think that is bit too much asked from that transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 5**
Here is a plot of the nine points:

[image: nine points]

- the blue lines show the pattern of the 3x3 = nine points in system 1 coordinates (three non straight lines)
- the black lines show the pattern in system 2 coordinates (three straight lines)
- the cyan lines show the transformed system 1 points (transformed by the affine transform $T$, note that they repeat the pattern)
- the green arrows show the mapping system 1 to system 2
- the red arrows show the differences from system 2 to the results of the affine transform

**Update 4**

Here is a plot:

[image: the mappings]

- The red triangle is formed by the points from system $1$.
- The green triangle is formed by the points from system $2$ which is congruent
  to the output of the affine map.
- The blue triangle is the result of the best linear map (minimizing least squares, $||.||_2$).
- The point at the lower base of the triangles is that extra point given in the question.

**Update 3**

BTW in this case, where we just use 3 points from each system, the matrices $A$ and $B$ are quadratic and we can simply calculate
$$
T = B A^{-1}
$$
this gives the same matrix for $T$.

If you want to use more points or have measured values with errors, you should stick to the least squares fit method below.

**Update 2**

The second kind of transformation I wanted to check is the affine transformation. It is heavily used in computer graphics, because it allows to represent translations as well in contrast to linear transformations which "only" handle scaling, rotation, mirroring, shearing (and perhaps more, but not translations). The other nice bit is that transformations can be combined by performing matrix multiplications.
The 3D case should be described in any good book on OpenGL for example.
Last not least there is a connection to projective geometry, so certain projections might be represented well.

So I used the methods used below, to determine a good affine transformation.

Here we have [homogenous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), which add one dimension. In normalized form the points we want to map look like this:
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right) 
$$

and we are going for an affine transformation
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} \\
t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} \\
t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33} 
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right) 
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x' \\
y' \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
We have 
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
50  &  70 & 100 \\
120 & 150 & 100 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad
B =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
20 & 90 & 190 \\
60 & 200 & 30 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

and using $(\#)$ this gives
$$
T = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
     3.42105 &    0.05263 & -157.36842 \\
     1.00000 &    4.00000 & -470.00000 \\
     0.00000 &    0.00000 &    1.00000
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and this transformation maps the systems $1$ and $2$ very nice:
$$
T A - B = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
  -1.3927e-12 & -2.3022e-12 & -1.8758e-12 \\
  -1.1369e-12 & -2.6148e-12 & -2.2169e-12 \\
  -1.5543e-14 & -1.6209e-14 & -1.6986e-14
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
which is practically zero. And
$$
T 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
75 \\
110 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
105.00000 \\
45.00000 \\
1.00000
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
so $(75,110)^T$ gets mapped to $(105, 45)^T$.

**Update 1**
I was not sure if $(\#)$ would result in the least square fit, so I am trying now to use $(*)$ directly on $T$, which is playing the role of the unknown $x$ in $(*)$:
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
t_{11} & t_{12} \\
t_{21} & t_{22}
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y
\end{matrix}
\right) 
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{matrix}
\right)
\iff \\
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x & y
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
t_{11} \\
t_{12}
\end{matrix}
\right) 
=
x'
\quad\wedge\quad
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x & y
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
t_{21} \\
t_{22}
\end{matrix}
\right) 
=
y' \iff \\
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x & y & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & x & y
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
t_{11} \\
t_{12} \\
t_{21} \\
t_{22}
\end{matrix}
\right) 
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
This leads to the system
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{21} & a_{22} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{31} & a_{32} \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
t_{11} \\
t_{12} \\
t_{21} \\
t_{22}
\end{matrix}
\right) 
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
b_{11} \\
b_{12} \\
b_{21} \\
b_{22} \\
b_{31} \\
b_{32}
\end{matrix}
\right) \iff \\
\hat{A} \hat{x} = \hat{b}
$$
with the least square fit solution
$$
\hat{x} = (\hat{A}^T \hat{A})^{-1} \hat{A}^T \hat{b}
$$
with $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{ij})$ as given in $(**)$ below.

Doing the calculation, I get
$$
\hat{x} =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
   2.71171 \\
  -0.78807 \\
  -1.11853 \\
   1.48915
\end{matrix}
\right) 
$$
which is the same as the $T$ calculated below.

**Original Answer**

Put the first two vectors $a_i$ of the first system into $A = (a_1; a_2)$,
and the first two vectors $b_i$ of the second system into $B = (b_1; b_2)$.
Then the wanted linear transformation $T$ should fullfill

$$
T A = B \iff T = B A^{-1}
$$

Using octave to calculate your example, I get:
$$
T =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    8.6667  & -3.4444 \\
   16.6667  & -6.4444
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

And indeed $Ta_1 = b_1$ and $T a_2 = b_2$, but $T a_3 = (522.22, 1022.22)^T \ne b_3$.

In that case on can try to go for a best fit:

If $A$ has more equations than necessary (more rows than columns), one goes over to a modified system:
$$
A x = b \Rightarrow A^T A x = A^T b \quad (*)
$$
It can be shown that the resulting solution $x$ is the best least squares fit ($||.||_2$).

$$
A =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
50  &  70 & 100 \\
120 & 150 & 100
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad
B =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
20 & 90 & 190 \\
60 & 200 & 30
\end{matrix}
\right) \quad (**)
$$

going for 
$$
T A = B \Rightarrow T A A^T = B A^T \iff T = B A^T (A A^T)^{-1} \quad (\#)
$$
gives 
$$
T =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
   2.71171 &  -0.78807 \\
  -1.11853 &  1.48915
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
but this is not a good approximation:
$$
T A = (T a_1; T a_2; T a_3) = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
41.017  &  71.610 & 192.364 \\
122.771 &  145.075 & 37.062
\end{matrix}
\right) \\
T A - B = (T a_1 - b_1; T a_2 - b_2; T a_3 - b_3) = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
   21.0175 & -18.3903 &   2.3645 \\
   62.7713 & -54.9249 &   7.0618
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
only the last vector has reasonable deviation, so I suppose an error in your task, or in my calculation.

PS 
$$
T (75, 110)^T = (116.691,79.917)^T
$$

PPS

```
octave:13> a1 = [50,120]'
a1 =

    50
   120

octave:14> a3 = [100,100]'
a3 =

   100
   100

octave:28> a2 = [70;150]
a2 =

    70
   150

octave:35> a = [ a1'; a2'; a3']'
a =

    50    70   100
   120   150   100

octave:36> b1 = [20;60]
b1 =

   20
   60

octave:37> b2 = [90;200]
b2 =

    90
   200

octave:38> b3 = [190;30]
b3 =

   190
    30

octave:41> b = [b1';b2';b3']'
b =

    20    90   190
    60   200    30

octave:42> a
a =

    50    70   100
   120   150   100

octave:43> b
b =

    20    90   190
    60   200    30

octave:45> a * a'
ans =

   17400   26500
   26500   46900

octave:46> inv(a * a')
ans =

   4.1209e-04  -2.3284e-04
  -2.3284e-04   1.5289e-04

octave:47> t = (b * a') * inv(a * a')
t =

   2.71171  -0.78807
  -1.11853   1.48915

octave:58> t * a
ans =

    41.017    71.610   192.364
   122.771   145.075    37.062

octave:59> t * a - b
ans =

   21.0175  -18.3903    2.3645
   62.7713  -54.9249    7.0618

octave:63> t * [75;110]
ans =

   116.691
    79.917
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but, how do you compute $A^{-1}$? Is this the pseudoinverse of $A$, $(A A^T)^{-1}$?

Comment: See above. That approximation is not good.

Comment: @mvw, if we want to do a non-linear transformation, what are the different techniques we can explore? also, a non-linear transformation doesn't necessarily mean a more accurate representation right?

Comment: Your task is finding some transformation function $T$ which should give $T(a_i) = b_i$ (here three sample points) and then be used for more points $T(u) = v$. Maybe you want to put all points on the lines between the $a_i$ through it, $u = (1 - \lambda) a_i + \lambda a_j$ and expect $T(u;\lambda)$ to be a straight line as well (what a linear mapping would deliver, I think). Anyway that task is solved by many methods, from fitting linear functions, using splines or such, up to using machine learning or whatever prediction technique.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = (x_i,y_i)$ be a $2\times 3$ array made up from your known points and $Y = (x_i^*,y_i^*)$ a $2\times 3$ array constituted by the transformed points, which are also known. Then you seek for a linear transformation such that:

$$Y = M \, X,$$ where $M$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix. Then you can solve the above equation for $M$ as follows:

$$M = Y X^T (X X^T)^{-1},$$ where $T$ denotes matrix transposition.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

PD: Please let me know if I made any mistake or wrote any mathematical incongruence.

Comment: @Dmoreno, what if we say, we have point (75,110) on system1, is it possible to find its transformed point on system2?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I can't see now how to build a (general) transformation matrix $M$ to go to coord. system 1 to 2.

Comment: The problem is that the transformation from $1$ to $2$ seems not linear. The $T$ I gave is an approximation to the unknown transformation. @IvanMatala Do you have any more information what kind of transformation might apply between systems $1$ and $2$?

Comment: @mvw currently I dont have any more information. This problem boggles me yesterday, and cant find a solution

Comment: @mvw,, is it possible to use a non linear transformation, like involving higher order polynomials? exponentials? splines?

Comment: You can make any assumption on the mapping. What might happen is that you have not enough or too many given data points to nail it. Here there was one point more than needed for a linear mapping, so we had to do some kind of taking the best mapping.

Comment: @mvw, would you mind giving to me / posting the associated octave history commands? i want to do it also. thanks

Comment: @IvanMatala I added it. I cut out my trials in between, in case you wonder about the numbering. Thanks to emacs keyboard macro facility, which allowed me to add the 4 spaces needed for the SO quoting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16245/discussion-between-ivanmatala-and-mvw).

Comment: @Dmoreno, ive tried your method.. Lets say I have A and B matrices..  X = [10,45,75,25,45,65,15,50,70;75,80,65,50,60,55,30,25,30]
Y = [0,400,800,0,400,800,0,400,800;600,600,600,300,300,300,0,0,0]   and I computed matrix M.. Why is that if I compute M*[10;75], it returns a different value (I get [-55.0504;590.5031]) rather than [0;600]? Thanks!

Comment: @Dmoreno http://puu.sh/aQhgS/e11d3234bc.png there is my matrices X and Y